# How to make org file type link search work with numbers?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I am trying to using a link to jump to a number in another org file. Searching for keyword numbers works for internal links but does not when searching in a different file. It works with words but not numbers? Why is this and can it be fixed?

a.org:

```
abcd or << abcd>> <br>
1234 or even <<1234>>

[[1234]] (works)
```

b.org:

```
[[file:./a.org::1234]] (does not work)<br>
[[file:./a.org::abcd]] (works)
```

Comment: In `[[file:./a.org::1234]]` the number is interpreted as a line number to go to. That was deemed more useful behavior than searching for the literal number. In `[[1234]]` there is no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, in `[[file:./a.org::1234]]` the number is interpreted as a line number. The only way to turn it into a search string  is to include an adjacent non-numeric character. E.g. you can find the string "1234 " (note the space at the end) by using `[[file:./a.org::1234 ]]` (again, note the space at the end). Other than that, Org mode does not provide an escape syntax to let a number be interpreted as a search string.